# What adverb, typical of AmEng, coincides most with the BrEng meaning of "quite" [=to a noticeable or partial extent]?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, american-english, british-english, word-usage

As long as -- seemingly -- the adverb "quite" in AmEng idiomatically carries an emphatic sense to it -- pretty much similar to saying "completely" or "absolutely" as in, "That girl looks quite pretty!" -- what adverb (or phrase, or grammatical construction) would Americans typically use -- in speech and writing -- that would coincide most with the chiefly BrEng meaning of "quite" [=to a noticeable or a partial degree]?

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Quite?s=t

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Pretty?s=t

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Rather?s=t

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Fairly?s=t

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Somewhat?s=t

Would they more likely say something like:

> - That girl looks somewhat pretty.
> - That girl looks rather pretty.
> - That girl looks fairly pretty.
> - That girl looks not too [...].
> - That girl looks pretty to some degree (or extent, or point).
>
> Etc.

Or, would they rather use a "-ly" ending adverb and say:

> - That girl looks moderately pretty.
> - That girl looks passably pretty.
> - That girl looks partially pretty.
>
> Etc.

In informal contexts, would they more likely say something like:

> - That girl looks sort of/kind of (sorta/kinda) pretty.
> - That girl looks some pretty.
> - That girl doesn't look too [...].
>
> Etc.

Consider the phrase, "That girl looks...pretty" merely as an example. The adverb (or phrase, or construction" should also work with other examples of BrEng "quite", e.g. "I'm quite well".

Comment: You've chosen the adjective cunningly!

Comment: Americans also use *quite* in the British sense. It can be quite confusing. (Although I believe in speech you can usually distinguish the two senses by the stress pattern.)

Comment: British English has both the above senses ((1) [to the fullest degree/extent] you're quite right; quite the opposite. (2) (not used with a negative) to a noticeable or partial extent; somewhat: she's quite pretty.) [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quite).

Comment: @PeterShor I agree with you for spoken contexts, but how about in writing? As you said quite correctly, it can sometimes be quite confusing to the reader, especially when there's no apparent punctuation to make the meaning of a sentence clear. Actually, I'm looking for an adverb somewhat less formal than "somewhat", but a bit more than "pretty". Plus, it should coincide fairly well with the sense to "quite".

Comment: EdwinAshworthm I was aware of that distinction in BrE for "quite right", "quite the opposite". That's what I was taught in school. But I thought the "to a partial extent" sense to "quite" was pretty much more BrE than AmE. Plus, I've always been taught that "pretty" was "a tad" more colloquial than "quite" or "rather" for instance, but not as informal as "kind of" and "sort of".

Comment: Sorry, NG; I was replying to Peter's comment and should have indicated that.

Comment: Gourmet!  You chose an exceptionally bad example ("pretty" == attractive), because, **'pretty' is easily the most common modifier in AmE!!**

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm nowhere near unfamiliar to that fact, Joe. "Pretty" is indeed the best fit here for spoken contexts. But I chose that "bad" example purposely, as long as I was looking (and still am) an adverb (or idiomatic construction) that can work for both spoken and written settings. Aside from in currency, I would like it to sit somewhere between "pretty" and "somewhat" on the formality scale. "Somewhat" actually sounds "a tad" too formal to my ear for colloquial contexts, and "pretty" not enough to fit for business and not so formal writing.

Comment: @JoeBlow, All things considered, I'm seriously starting to wonder if there's any such word or phrase in AmE today. After all, "fairly" might be the best option here, ALA it doesn't sound overly formal or informal, it's relatively common in modern day AmE, and can fit in both spoken and "not so formal" written contexts.

Comment: it's a tough one. i've been working on a lot of Y.A. lately and I really can't (quite) think of anything a california teenager would say along the lines.  "that's a fairly nice car"  "she's fairly attractive" etc - tricky!

Comment: You could say, "That girl is pretty enough." The meaning is, more or less, that the girl is indeed pretty, although she could be more pretty. This may emphasize the lack of the quality more than saying "quite" would, though, and as such might not be exactly what you had in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As nobody has picked up on it, I'll post as an answer.

Perhaps the most commonly used secondary modifier meaning 'quite/fairly' in US English is **pretty**. But it doesn't work here for obvious reasons. (Well, one obvious reason.)

Comment: But isn't "pretty" a bit more informal than "quite", esp. for written contexts? Also, does it coincide fairly well with the sense that is carried by "quite"? I thought that saying "I'm pretty well" sat somewhere between "BrE" "quite" and "very"

Comment: Yes, but you did ask for 'in speech' as well as 'in writing'. And notice that there are differences between 'to a noticeable degree' and 'to a partial degree': even 'this sense' has conflicting meanings. There's a difference between 'quite' in ..'Does she have a chance of the modelling job?' ..'I think so – she's quite pretty, you know' and ..'Do you think she'll get the modelling job?' ..'Well, she's _quite_ pretty, but no Helen of Troy'.

Comment: Well, I meant an adverb or the like that can fit for spoken and written contexts. Regarding "to a noticeable or partial degree; somewhat" it's the definition to "quite" I found in the CD online http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quite

Comment: For instance, would "pretty" work in AmE for all but the most formal prose, like business writing?

Comment: NG: 'pretty' is more informal. So not for newspapers or 'educated' speech. Also note a common way to say this is 'real' as in "That girl is real pretty".

Comment: In BrE "quite" is informal, and not for newspapers or educated speech.

Comment: @Joe Blow Is that just an opinion (it's different from my perception), or have you evidence? [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quite?showCookiePolicy=true) makes no mention of register for any of the senses of 'quite', though it certainly flags for informality (eg [daft](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/daft?showCookiePolicy=true) ) whereas other dictionaries might not.

Comment: @JoeBlow Sure enough "quite" is less formal than "somewhat" for both speech and writing. Still and all, it doesn't sound anywhere near as informal as "pretty", especially for business and not so formal writing. All things said, I think I should change the question in the OP to: what adverb -- that is not as informal as "pretty" and not as formal as "somewhat", plus coincides fairly well with BrE "quite" -- is typically (or generally) used in AmR for business and not so formal writing.

Answer (score 1):

Like you say, in AmE, *quite beautiful* is more akin to *very beautiful*.

By the way, we do use the phrase *not quite*, meaning something akin to *not in a noticeable or measurable amount*.

But using the examples from the [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/quite_1) (which are similar to yours), I can give some more common ways we would express the same meaning of *a little or a lot but not completely*:

1. I'm quite tired but I can certainly walk a little further.
   (replacing *quite*): *very*, *a little*, *a bit*, *somewhat*, (vernacular) *sort of*, *kind of*
2. There was quite a lot of traffic today but yesterday was even busier.
   (replacing *quite a lot of*): *a lot of*, *quite a bit of*, *some*,
3. It was quite a difficult job.
   (replacing *quite a*): *a very*, *somewhat of a*, *a bit of a*
4. He's quite attractive but not what I'd call gorgeous.
   (replacing *quite*): *very*, *somewhat*, (vernacular) *really*, *sort of*, *kind of*
5. It would be quite a nuisance to write to everyone.
   (replacing *quite a*): *a big*, *somewhat of a*, *a minor*, *a small*

These suggestions don't constitute a comprehensive list, but the point is the in AmE, I wouldn't often hear or see a predetereminer that is as nonspecific as *quite* appears to be (as in *a little or a lot but not completely*, per the Cambridge Dictionaries Online definition).

Quite often, in many cases like these, the adjective predeterminer wouldn't be used at all.

Comment: It's not a predeterminer. Traditionalists lump these things in the adverb catch-all; they are nowadays often called 'degree modifiers', but this isn't logical for ones with semantic content (frighteningly realistic). The term 'secondary [pre-]modifiers' (of (a) adjectives, (b) adverbs) may catch on.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's like everything I learned about English in the last two hours is wrong (head explodes!). Where can I find some good background on that?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on English Determiners is a good start. You can look up various articles on 'degree modifiers'. [Here](http://www.berkeleyhigh.org/features/slang/) is quite a demanding article; [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143997/how-do-you-modify-an-adverb-with-another-adverb) is a previous article.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is **'quite'**. It can be and is used in exactly the same manner in AmE as BrE

Comment: It's not so obvious to me, and I am an American. Could you explain?

Comment: There is no difference in usage of the word quite between BrE and AmE in this context.  I don't even know if it is less common, but that isn't what he asked.

Comment: They are utterly different, not even close.  It's one of the clearest differences I can think of it yank versus pommie english.

Comment: As an American, I've got to disagree that "quite pretty" would generally be understood to mean "somewhat pretty".

Comment: And I have heard BrE users to use 'quite pretty' to mean 'very pretty'. So what?

Answer (score 0):

**Excellent answer Edwin**, I agree with you "pretty _ _ _" is the closest.

A fundamental problem here is that British humour is quirky, confusing, and self-mocking whereas AmE humour is matey, straightforward and plainsong. In the UK you can use just-slightly-archaic words (like quite) and there can be a shade of communication that you're using one of those old-fashioned British terms. (Note too that "Quite." is used on it's own as a figure of speech, meaning "I agree with you, and we're both terribly British"  :) )

## Also, note...

.

**The example, " _ _ _ pretty" is very confusing, because, there IS NO common modifier for that word in AmE.**

You never say, in colloquial AmE, "a bit pretty" or similar.  (The only one I can think of is "Damn' pretty!" in some situations.)

(Indeed, it might be that the *reason* there is no modifier for "pretty" (attractive) is that the usual colloquial modifier in the US, is, indeed, "pretty!")

I definitely agree with Edwin, *pretty* is "the translation of" *quite*.  Good one.

Pretty good.

Quite good.

That's the closest you're ever gonna get in the very subtle differences between AmE and BrE.

Comment: "Pretty" is considered informal [=suitable for colloquial speech and the funnies in the back of some newspapers] "quite" and "fairly" are not. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/pretty http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english-thesaurus/quite